# HTML/CSS : Making an <a> tag with css

Tags: html, css

I have a phone number and I want to make it linkable with CSS. The phone number is a background (CSS) inserted in a div. Is this possible with CSS?

the probleme is ... i have a lot of pages and i have only a css page linked to all that pages.
"no JS" and i don't want to go all around changing "div" by "a".

Answer (score 2):

Yep, instead of a `div` use an `a` element in this way:

```
a.phone-number {
    display: block;
    width: ...;
    height: ...;
    background: url(...);
}
```

and then your html will be

```
<a href="#url#" class="phone-number"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

stead of `div` make it a background-image of an `a` example below

hmtl

```
<a href="#">phone</a>
```

css

```
a.{
float:left;
width:100px; 
height:200px;
text-indent:-5000px;
background: url(images/sample.jpg);
}
```

hopefully it help

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot create links with CSS. CSS is for rendering suggestions, not for enhancing the functionality or adding new elements.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<div class="number"></div>
```

---

```
.number{ /* mention the div class name or id here */
    display:inline;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand; /*for cross-browser support */
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue; /* give your own color */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an `<a>` tag.  The `<a>` is the semantically correct element to use giving your markup more meaning.

Using HTML5 you should mark up your telephone link like so.

```
<a href="tel:+13174562564">317-456-2564</a>
```

This allows mobile devices such as iPhones and Androids to recognise it as a phone number and will initiate a phone call when touched.